# Objective C - what does & sign mean when used in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, syntax

what does & sign mean when used in objective c
for example?

```
int i = 1;
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:&i length:sizeof(i)];
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's C.

& == address of

so, &i is the "address of i".